GCP Vertex AI init
I am getting an error message when I tried to run the following code
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

PROJECT_ID = <project id>
REGION = <region> # "europe-west4"
# Path to your service account key file
key_path = #Path to the json key associated with service account from google cloud

Create credentials object
credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(
key_path,
scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

if credentials.expired:
    credentials.refresh(Request())

Initialize Vertex AI SDK
vertexai.init(project=PROJECT_ID, location=REGION, credentials=credentials)

I am getting this error message when executing the cell.
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the current cell or a previous cell. 
Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. 


Hi@ Vallalar_dev, Could you please upgrade the latest version of Google cloud SDK and python. also update the kernal pip install --upgrade ipykernel. Let me if this helps you or not?

I am still getting the error message. Now I am getting the same error when I trigger the LLM model invoke.        response = model_1.invoke(prompt). using model: "gemini-pro"

Hi @Vallalar_dev, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
